# What is the appropriate word for "give/contain information"

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request

I have the following sentence:

> It contains all the information **that tells** what one is thinking about.

What I am trying to say is that this thing gives/contains an information. I want to make sure that "**that tells**" is appropriate for this purpose. And if there are words that could give the expression a better structure.

Comment: Do you want words to replace "an information giving object" or do you want to replace "that gives/ contains" ?

Comment: @VarunKN, I want replace "that tells"

Comment: What if you struck the "tells what" part? _It contains all the information that one is thinking about._

Comment: @J.R. My question basically; Is there something wrong in using **that tells**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with something similar to J.R.'s suggestion:

> It contains all the information **on** what one is thinking about.

Prepositions **on** or about are commonly used (with *information*) to convey that the thing mentioned has something as a topic (see [ODO def 3](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/on)).

Since you already have one *about* used at the end, to avoid repetition you can go with *on* and get the same meaning.

Example of such usage:

> *The pamphlet provides a lot of information on recent changes to the tax laws.*

From: [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/information)

An aside: this [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=information+that+tells%2C+information+on%2C+information+about&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinformation%20that%20tells%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinformation%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinformation%20about%3B%2Cc0) gives a rough image of how often *information on* is used.

"Information that tells" is not ungrammatical, but it sounds unidiomatic to me.

Comment: Another aside: I cannot imagine the sort of information you are talking about - what would contain the information on another persons thoughts (?), so I'm guessing that this is a hypothetical sentence. It would work better with a slightly different example.

Answer (score 1):

If you are married to the rest of the sentence then:

> It contains all the information describing what one is thinking about.

Otherwise:

> It contains the descriptions of all of one's thoughts.